# ThingsBoard on ECS

Tags: docker-compose, amazon-ecs, thingsboard

I try to deploy ThingsBoard on ECS using the Docker Compose ECS integration: I set up an external database, I write the Docker Compose File

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  thingsboard:
    container_name: thingsboard
    image: thingsboard/tb-postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://<HOST>:<PORT>/thingsboard?sslmode=require
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=<USERNAME>
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=<PASSWORD>
    ports:
      - '9090:9090'
      - '1883:1883'
      - '5683:5683/udp'
```

and I launch the stack on ECS using `docker compose up`.

The cluster is correctly created and I can see from CloudWatch logs that the ThingsBoard container starts correctly (even if it is *very* slow).

After a while, though, ECS deregisters the tasks due to health check failures.

The ECS Event logs say:

```
service thingsboard-ThingsboardService-XXX (port 9090) is unhealthy in target-group thing-Thing-XXX due to (reason Health checks failed).

service thingsboard-ThingsboardService-XXX (port 1883) is unhealthy in target-group thing-Thing-XXX due to (reason Health checks failed).

service thingsboard-ThingsboardService-XXX (port 5683) is unhealthy in target-group thing-Thing-XXX due to (reason Health checks failed).
```

Modifying the health check configuration, I am able at least to login into ThingsBoard and check that everything works the right way. After few minutes, though, the health check failure repeats and the tasks are stopped.

Why is that?

Comment: How do you persist data?

Comment: RDS Postgres database: `jdbc:postgresql://[...]`.

Answer (score 0):

Those ports are not HTTP ports. 9090 is gRPC. 1883 is MQTT, 5683 is CoAP. Most likely, the health checks are not expecting those protocols. I would recommend disabling them and checking for HTTP(S) only.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm gonna check your suggestion ASAP.

Comment: How would one disable the health checks? I can't seem to find the option. I can't seem to get my Thingsboard instance running as it is constantly deregistering even if I check HTTP only.